# Can't scrape particular websites using Scrapinghub

Tags: scrapinghub

I am using the autoscraping feature in the scrapinghub service.

While building and deploying the autoscraper, I found that the site I wanted to scrape would never return any Requests, and would time out around 3.5 minutes.

So, I began reading the documentation to see if I could figure out why this was happening ([How to check if site is suitable for autoscraping](http://support.scrapinghub.com/topic/198490-how-to-check-if-site-is-suitable-for-autoscraping/)).

I followed the steps and temporarily removed Javascript from my browser (chrome) and found that I had no problems viewing the site I wanted to scrape.

My question is, at risk of sounding vague, what might be some other reasons that a site is not scrapeable, aside from Javascript? Are there some other ideas regarding how to diagnose a problem like this?

Comment: Hello, could you please share the link to the site you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I recognize you from the tutorials on facebook! :)
The URL is here:
http://goo.gl/tk5qb